# Why won't the audio on my Qt app play through the large speakers on the phone?

Tags: android, c++, qt, audio

I am writing a qt 5.1 android app and I am playing some audio files but they are playing from the ear speaker and not the speaker phone speaker. I know when you are writing apps in for android in java you can use the audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true) call  but I am writing this in cpp on qt 5.1. I was wondering if anybody else was having problems with this and if it is possible to solve?

Comment: Does the API have any support for specifying an Android audio stream type? Sounds like your audio is being routed according to `STREAM_VOICE_CALL`.

Comment: Just a random guess, but if your Android device is a Nexus 5 or runs 4.4 KitKat then there may be problems with the OS audio driver.  http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/qvofwTXka28

Comment: Its happening on a motorola droid 2, motorola razr, and samsung galaxy s3. I dont know if the api can specify this an audio stream type.